# defined function in Smarty not work

Tags: php, function, smarty

I defined a function `pagination` in `global.tpl` and then I included `global.tpl` in `header.tpl` and I included the `header.tpl` in all of my template files, so `global.tpl` should be include in all of my template files too.

Now when I trying to use `{pagination}` I got the `Unknown tag` in result, but when I place the `pagination` function in each file there is no any problem.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `{call name=pagination}` instance of `{pagination}` 
more information : http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.call.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`{call}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.call.tpl) tag to invoke functions that have been defined on another template, as in

```
{call name=pagination}
```

Another option would be to create a plugin from code with [`registerPlugin`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl); you can do this in your `Smarty` derived class and it will be directly available to use from all templates.